# Python - list index query

Tags: python, list

I am learning python and trying to understanding the list and seem to be comfortable but come across condition which i need help with. Would appreciate if someone can explain.
Note: Using Python 2.7.6

```
def d_list(x):
  for i in x:
     print i , x.index(i) # expecting the list item and index to be returned
```

when i pass n = [3,5,4] to the function works file with output:

```
3 0
5 1
4 2
```

but when i pass n = [0,1,2] i get output:

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
```

should it not be 2 2 instead of 2 1 as last line should give index for list item 2.

```
PJ@tiny:~$ cat test.py
n = [0,1,2]
#n = [3,5,4]
def double_list(x):
     #for i in range(0, len(x)):
      #   x[i] = x[i] * 2
     for i in x:
         print i , x.index(i), x[x.index(i)]
         x[x.index(i)] = i * 2
     return x

print double_list(n)
PJ@tiny:~$ ^C
PJ@tiny:~$ python test.py
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 1 2
[0, 4, 2]
```

Heres the complete output and script. Note: commented for loop works fine i tried.

Comment: Please post a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are having. Please copy-paste its actual output and describe the expected output. See [mcve] and, more generally, [ask].

Comment: I run your code and it works well. `input: x = [0, 1, 2]` I got `0 1 2` and `index` `0 1 2`

Comment: Make sure you've saved the file, and are running the correct file if you're not running from the interpreter shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

Why your method of doubling a list does not work:

[index()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm) returns the index of the first element that matches the supplied element in the list. When you double 1 you get 2. You then do x.index(2) which returns i=1 and doubles the element at i=1 again returning 4. The last element stays 2. Thus you get [0,4,2]

---

The pythonic way to iterate over a list while getting both the index and the value of each element in the list is with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html).

```
def d_list(x):
    for i, val in enumerate(x):
        print i, val
```

Comment: Hi, Agree and as i am learning i wanted to know why my index is not returning the right value. Appreciate your answer

Comment: I updated my answer with why your method does not work.

Comment: This is what is happening step by step:
    0 0 0 x[0] = 0 * 2 = 0   [0,1,2]
    1 1 1
    x[1] = 1 * 2 = 2   [0,2,2]
    2 1 2
    x[2] = 2 * 2 = 4    [0,4,2]

Comment: This is what is happening step by step:
'0 0 0'
'x[0] = 0 * 2 = 0  #  [0,1,2]'
'1 1 1'
'x[1] = 1 * 2 = 2   [0,2,2]'
'2 1 2'
'x[2] = 2 * 2 = 4    [0,4,2]'
So reiterating through list as suggested should use enumerate.Unlike most basic programming courses/book suggest